# When editing a post, should I Americanize spelling?

Tags: support, faq, editing

I am editing a post, and cleaning up general formatting, spelling, and grammar.  Is is OK to also Americanize spelling  (eg, change "behaviour" to "behavior")?

Answer (score 2):

In general, changing spelling from American to British or British to American isn't seen as an improvement because it implies that one is *wrong*, when in fact both are *correct*.  Leave the original as-is.

See also:

- [What should the standard spelling be - British or US?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us)